# Cyclic Timeout Event Double Looping

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to use a cyclic event countdown to trigger certain functions. However, the problem I am facing is that the event in my model seems to double run at each trigger. An example is shown in the screenshot, where at each trigger, the model time is printed twice instead of once. I tried creating this on a totally new model, but the occurrence cannot be replicated. Is there any settings in AnyLogic that I may have edited that is causing this?

[image: Event setup]
[image: Console run]
[image: Number of traceln functions used]

Comment: if i what i suggested doesn't work, can you try to look for time() instead of "traceln" to know where you are using it ... because there are some other ways to print such as System.out.print(time());

Comment: also, is this a normal experiment? or are you doing parameter variation or some other type of experiment?

Comment: it's suspicious though that the name of your event in your properties is "event" while in the search bar it's ev_Downtime... how do you explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't replicate it because that's not the root cause of your problem...

click ctrl+F to find a string on your project
write down "traceln" to find everywhere where you are using the traceln function

It is certain that you are using it somewhere else to print the time...

Comment: Hi Felipe, thanks for the answer, there was some discrepancy in the naming of the last screenshot. This was due to an error on my side as I renamed the event before taking the screenshot, but it was referring to the same event. Nevertheless, I couldn't discover the issue triggering this situation, and as it cant be replicated, I have proceeded with other alternatives to resolve the issue. Thank you very much for your advices :)